# Can 3 objects be replaced by 1 object, or joined by their location? (BGE)

Tags: game-engine

I have a crane loading three 40' long pipes onto rollers to be welded, end-to-end to make a 120' long pipe. (The pics are not to scale, just a mock-up):

[image: 3-40'Pipes on Rollers, Pipeyard to the left]
3-40'Pipes on Rollers, Pipeyard to the left

On keypress "W" the rollers turn once with robotic welders joining the 3-40' pipes. I used the actuator EditObject/EndObject to remove the 3-40' pipes and an EditObject/AddObject to replace them with one 120' pipe on the rollers so it can be lifted from the rollers onto a truck.

[image: 1-120' Pipe replaces 3-40' pipes on keypress "W"]
1-120' Pipe replaces 3-40' pipes on keypress "W"

Problem with that is the pipes in the pipeyard also disappear. So, my question is...can the 3-40' pipes on the rollers be JOINED, or replaced, by their LOCATION on the rollers rather than by assigning EditObject to each pipe? Animation won't work because I need to move the finished pipe to the truck with the crane.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BGE does not support mesh manipulation that way. You can scale the objects (forming a longer Pipe) but you can't merge meshes.

When you let all objects listen to the same even (<kbd>w</kbd>) with the exact same behavior, they will behave exact the same way by ending themselves at the same time. This is what you told them to do.

What you wanted to do is to end the objects on the rollers. So you need to discriminate between objects on the rollers and objects that are not on the rollers. To be more specific you need to identify the three small pipes that can form the big pipe.

You could

- check what pipes are on the rollers. This excludes all other pipes.
- check what orientation they have. This excludes misaligned pipes.
- check the location. This excludes pipes too far away.

How to do?

- You could assume that any pipe on a specific roller is already placed and aligned correctly
- Check all three rollers to have a pipe on top of itself
- or let the pipes check themselves if they are above a roller

Checking options:

- ray sensor (upward or downward)
- collision sensor
- radar sensor
- near sensor
- check via python

Comment: Well, that gives me quite a few options to check out. Your ideas are appreciated!